# Regular expression to match a pattern and print it to next line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a textfile with data delimited with '|'. The sample data looks like:

```
584|Daily Support Calls - PQRS Group Practice and ACO GPRO Web Interface|N2TM      |01/28/2015|01.00.00|PM  |01/28/2015|02.00.00|PM  |IN|Y|NULL|N2TM      ||https://rti-events3.webex.com/rti-events3/onstage/g.php?MTID=ef4a250ead6cb06bad08d8e9ca3cb07ba|Daily support calls during the first week of GPRO Web Interface submission period.
Topic:  Daily Support Calls - PQRS Group Practice and ACO GPRO Web Interface 
Date:   Wednesday, January 28, 2015
Time:   1:00 pm -2:00 pm ET
You may join the event online or by phone. Please use only 1 of the 2 options shown below.
Option 1: To join the online event
1. Click on the link provided above.
2. Click "Join Now."
Option 2: To join the event by telephone only
US TOLL: 1-650-479-3207
Access code: 993 566 829
Event password: gpro128|2015-02-03-13.21.30.421193|2015-02-03-16.55.46.580524
585|Daily Support Calls - PQRS Group Practice and ACO GPRO Web Interface|N2TM      |01/29/2015|01.00.00|PM  |01/29/2015|02.00.00|PM  |IN|Y|NULL|N2TM      ||https://rti-events3.webex.com/rti-events3/onstage/g.php?MTID=e4c555479a1fc58ba3064b28983cd6595|Daily support calls during the first week of GPRO Web Interface submission period.
Topic:  Daily Support Calls - PQRS Group Practice and ACO GPRO Web Interface 
Date:   Thursday, January 29, 2015
Time:   1:00 pm - 2:00 pm ET
You may join the event online or by phone. Please use only 1 of the 2 options shown below.
Option 1: To join the online event
1. Click on the link provided above.
2. Click "Join Now."
Option 2: To join the event by telephone only
US TOLL: 1-650-479-3207
Access code: 991 837 559
Event password: gpro129|2015-02-03-13.26.46.870448|2015-02-03-13.27.03.a
```

I want the result to be:

```
584|Daily Support Calls - PQRS Group Practice and ACO GPRO Web Interface|N2TM      |01/28/2015|01.00.00|PM  |01/28/2015|02.00.00|PM  |IN|Y|NULL|N2TM      ||https://rti-events3.webex.com/rti-events3/onstage/g.php?MTID=ef4a250ead6cb06bad08d8e9ca3cb07ba|Daily support calls during the first week of GPRO Web Interface submission period.|Topic:  Daily Support Calls - PQRS Group Practice and ACO GPRO Web Interface |Date:   Wednesday, January 28, 2015|Time:   1:00 pm -2:00 pm ET|You may join the event online or by phone. Please use only 1 of the 2 options shown below.|Option 1: To join the online event|1. Click on the link provided above.|2. Click "Join Now."|Option 2: To join the event by telephone only|US TOLL: 1-650-479-3207|Access code: 993 566 829|Event password: gpro128|2015-02-03-13.21.30.421193|2015-02-03-16.55.46.580524
585|Daily Support Calls - PQRS Group Practice and ACO GPRO Web Interface|N2TM      |01/29/2015|01.00.00|PM  |01/29/2015|02.00.00|PM  |IN|Y|NULL|N2TM      ||https://rti-events3.webex.com/rti-events3/onstage/g.php?MTID=e4c555479a1fc58ba3064b28983cd6595|Daily support calls during the first week of GPRO Web Interface submission period.|Topic:  Daily Support Calls - PQRS Group Practice and ACO GPRO Web Interface |Date:   Thursday, January 29, 2015|Time:   1:00 pm - 2:00 pm ET|You may join the event online or by phone. Please use only 1 of the 2 options shown below.|Option 1: To join the online event|1. Click on the link provided above.|2. Click "Join Now."|Option 2: To join the event by telephone only|US TOLL: 1-650-479-3207|Access code: 991 837 559|Event password: gpro129|2015-02-03-13.26.46.870448|2015-02-03-13.27.03.a
```

Basically some fields are occuring in new lines. I want them in a single line.

Comment: Are the newlines contained only in the last field? And are the number of fields constant? That makes it much easier than a generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern/replacement:

```
search: \R(?!\d+\|)
replace: |
```

details:

`\R` is an alias for any kind of newline sequences (so including `\r`, `\r\n` and `\n`)

`(?!...)` is a negative lookahead. A test that means "not followed by"

`\d+` one or more digits

`\|` a literal |

Comment: @user1521306: What is your notepad++ version? Did you check the regex checkbox?